# What language does Zeno machines recognize?

Tags: hypercomputation

A Zeno machine of order 1 is a Turing machine that uses half the time it ran its $(n-1)$th step to run its nth step, hence can run infinite steps in just 2 seconds. This is called one step of order 1.

A Zeno machine of order $n$ is a Zeno machine of order $(n-1)$ that runs infinite steps (of order $n-1$) in $2^n$ seconds first step (of order $n$), but in $2^{n-1}$ seconds second step, and in $2^{n-m}$ seconds the mth step.

So, exactly what type of formal language is a Zeno machine of order $n$ capable of recognizing?

Comment: You haven't defined when a Zeno machine accepts an input.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_machine

Comment: AFAIK, anything that a Turing machine would recognize in infinite time.